# Prevent printing unit PSI (pounds per square inch) as Greek letter psi (Ψ)

Tags: r, ggplot2, units-of-measurement, ggforce

I'm plotting data using ggplot2 with the gWidgets2RGtk2 library.  The data has units set with the units library.  By using the library ggforce, it automatically puts the units in the axis labels of the plot.

The problem is if the data has the units psi (pounds per square inch) it displays the Greek letter psi "Ψ".  I'd like it to display "psi".

I'm not sure if the problem is in units, ggplot, or ggforce.

```
print(as.character(units(example_data$pressure)))
```

gives "psi".

```
library(data.table)
library(units)
library(ggforce)

example_data <- data.table(time = 1:3, pressure = c(5, 10, 20))
units(example_data$time) <- ud_units$s
units(example_data$pressure) <- ud_units$psi
p <- ggplot(data = example_data, mapping = aes(time, pressure)) + geom_line()
print(p)
print(as.character(units(example_data$pressure)))
```

Comment: It looks like this behavior is coming from `ggforce::scale_y_unit()` (which is being used implicitly when you have `ggforce` loaded and you provide a column of class `units`.) I don't know if there's a way to modify the behavior. For example if you try adding `+ scale_y_unit(name=NULL)`, you _still_ get the parsed units (greek character psi).